# Parseval theorem on a signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

If I have $ z(t) = x( t - \frac{ T_0 }{4 } ) $ with $ x(t) = rect ( \frac{ t - \frac{T_0}{4} } { \frac{T_0}{2} } $ I obtained that , For parseval theorem , $ Px= Pz = \frac{1}{4} sinc ^{2}( \frac{k}{2} ) $ but the result on my book is 1/2

Comment: What do $Px$ and $Pz$ mean? What are their definitions?

Comment: $ P_x = | X_k | ^{2} $ where $ X_k = f_0 X( k f_0 ) $

Comment: And what is $X$ (in terms of $x$ I suppose)?

Comment: X(f) is the Fourier transform of x(t) and And $ X(kf_0) $ is the Fourier transform of x when $ f=k f_0 $